# Add a text to the beginning of multiple files in multiple folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am writing a bash script and as a part of it, I need to do the following:

I have like 100 directories and their names are according to their write-time e.g 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05 and so on. Inside each of these directories I have two files "p" and "U". How can I add a line to the beginning of these files in all directories?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried to use "sed" but my main problem is that the time folders are somewhat arbitrary so I don't know how I should do it in each folder.

Comment: Show your efforts.

Comment: UNIX doesn't have folders, you probably mean directories. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
for i in `find . -name "[pU]" ` ; do echo "some string 3" > $i.new ; cat < $i >> $i.new ; mv -f $i.new $i; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`[0-9]*/[pU]` - is same as files `0/p, 0/U, 0.1/p, 0.1/U` etc

```
sed -i '1s/^/newlineContent\n/' [0-9]*/[pU]
```

Comment: @Eman - you should consider accepting answer of your questions - does not have to be mine - whichever answer helped you - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - i.e., make the correct sign green

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is equally good, but sorry I had to choose Roman's answer as he posted it earlier.

Comment: that is not a problem - as long as there is an accepted answer to let community know that your question is resolved : )

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly basically you need to do this:

1) put files and folders into seperate arrays (depending on your conditions which you will specify with "if"/"else" flow.

so, for files:
        files=(~/$j1/$2/temp1/*)

2) for loop over array and touch/mv files or whatever else you need done
then something like this:

for i in ${files[@]};
    do 
        touch $1_yourTextOrValFromFunction

## or

cat ~/$1/$2/temp1/*_temp > 1_yourTextOrValFromFunction

```
done
```